# Using different pod versions in the same project

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I have an iOS app that uses AFNetworking 1.x. And I want to use in this app another pod that uses AFNetworking 2.0. Is this possible?

When I execute pod install I'm getting the following error:

```
[!] Unable to satisfy the following requirements:
`AFNetworking (= 1.3.2)` required by `Podfile`- `AFNetworking (~> 2.0.3)` required by `AnotherPod (0.0.2)`
```

I was wondering if it would be possible to do it playing with `link_with` and `target` in the podfile. Or changing something in the `AnotherPod.podspec` file...

Some ideas?

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible. Because of the way C based languages work, any inclusion of multiple versions of the same framework would cause duplicate symbol errors (unless they changed everything entirely, which in this case is not true).

Comment: Keith Smiley, is this also true if the framework would be used by two different projects? e.g. AFNetworking 1 in project A and AFNetworking 2 in project B?